# Hybrid (React and ReactNative)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We're planning a project that targets both iOS and Browser, and are curious to how we can share as much as possible between the two, using React.

Can we build the project in (normal) React and somehow switch to React-native when building for iOS (and later Android)?

Comment: Ionic (AngularJS) gives you what you want. But I do understand why you want to use React instead of Angular. To me it would be awesome ReactNative created a `www` folder like the `ios` and `android` folders. I don't mind that the browser look and behaves like an iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React and React Native aren't 'write once, run anywhere' frameworks, as [Tom Occhino said](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1014532261909640/react-native-bringing-modern-web-techniques-to-mobile/)...it's more of a 'learn once, write anywhere' technology. That being said, your developers will be familiar with the syntax/best practices after writing your first implementation, and then should be able to smoothly transition and apply those same techniques to the browser or mobile app.

Much of your implementation and how they all function together will largely depend on the API you are getting your data from. If your API/data source is solid...then the rest will be a piece of cake!

So to answer your question...sure you can build the project in React and then switch to React Native when building your mobile apps. In fact, that's what the folks who are working tirelessly on the React/React Native teams are hoping you will do. Will you be able to use the exact same code? No.

Comment: Thanks, thats more or less what I understood too. What makes me curious though, is *why*. As React's renderer supports multiple backends (iOS, DOM as of now), there should not be anything technical that would prevent this.

(I understand that the UI _design_ (and best-practices in that domain) will probably warrant a specific implementation though.)

Comment: Just the fact that the environments are different and require different implementations (as you said). Obviously a ListView element (and all that that entails) doesn't make a  lot of sense on a web app for example, but makes perfect sense in an iOS environment.  In the same vein, a div has no place in iOS, but makes perfect sense in a web app. It's just two different worlds and would make things messy and less intuitive to try to shoehorn the two into a 'write once, run anywhere' solution.